# Arithmetically repeating digit $1$ with interval of $n$ keeping rest of the digits $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

I'm struggling to get a sequence of numbers $0$ and $1$ so that $1$ is repeating after a stable interval. For example:

$$\frac{(1-((-1)^{\lfloor\frac{n}{12}\rfloor} ((-1)^{\lfloor\frac{n}{11}\rfloor}))}{2}$$

will give:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,...
```

But what I really need is to repeat digit $1$ after every $12$ steps and keep rest of the digits $0$:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,
```

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,

I have tried with $mod$, $floor$, $ceiling$, $(-1)^n$ combinations, which I rather use instead of trigonometric functions or logical blocks, but haven't really made it.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_sequence).

Comment: @MarkokraM Just use a piecewise function... For example $\begin{cases}1&\text{if }12\mid n\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Comment: Is there any other way than using summation and trigonometry to do it?

Comment: @user202729 I rather use plain arithmetics if possible. I added this restriction to my question.

Comment: Although it's possible to do it, I don't understand why. This is not code-golf, and you probably want your formula to be clear rather than short.

Comment: This is part of the richer formula and I hope to simplify it uniformly later.

Answer (score 1):

One way with floor and ceiling is

$$1-\left\lceil\frac{n-12\left\lfloor\frac{n}{12}\right\rfloor}{12}\right\rceil=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $n\equiv 0\pmod{12}$}\\0&\text{if $n\not\equiv 0\pmod{12}$}\end{cases}$$